# How to demonstrate the lowest isolation levels for each transaction will not corrupt the database?

Tags: database

Next week i start my Exams, one of which being Databases. A Task in of our assignments still stumps me even after recieving the answer and im hoping someone can clarify or assist me in understanding the processs.

Below is the question

"Write a report on concurrent execution of two database transactions to demonstrate the
lowest isolation levels for each transaction will not corrupt the database."

```
Transaction T1:
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET VERIFY OFF
UPDATE DeptLocation
SET address = '23 Market street, Wollongong, NSW 2500'
WHERE d# = 2 AND address = '108 George Street, Sydney,
NSW 2000';
UPDATE Employee
SET salary = salary + 0.2 * salary;
COMMIT;

Transaction T2:
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK ON
SET VERIFY OFF
UPDATE Employee
SET address = '15 Kathryn St Kanahooka NSW 2530'
WHERE e# = '00150';
UPDATE DeptLocation
SET address = '23 Market street, Wollongong, NSW 2500'
WHERE d# = 2;
COMMIT;
```

Assume that a database user would like to concurrently run both transactions and assume
that in the same moment no other transactions will be processed. What the best isolation
levels would you execute each transaction at to avoid the corruption of the database and
to achieve the best performance for each transaction? You have 3 options: READ ONLY,
READ COMMITTED, and SERIALIZABLE.

Here is a single case answer provided to us. Apologies for it being a Screen capture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/550Yt.png

Im confused with the whole process, apologies if this is a Vague question but id appreciate it if anyone could assist in explaing how my professor got to that first Case result. Thankyou

Comment: @curiosa in terms of the solution provided by my professor. Why does T1 wait after the Employeee Update statement and why does T2 wait after the Update Address statement?

Comment: @curiosa just to make sure im on the right track i attempted another case if you dont mind going over it. https://i.imgur.com/HRRJZZL.png

Comment: @curiosa my reasoning. T1 updates Position and locks it so T2 cant update. T2 Attempts to read but as it was locked in a different transaction it fails, causes a deadlock and then aborts.  T1 commits. T2 Restarts.

Comment: @curiosa when i sit the exam its paper and pen so using a db installation isnt much help